# Are there hints in the game to find the bobbleheads?

Tags: fallout-4

Are there in game hints to find the bobbleheads or is it only by chance (or power of observation) that we find them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no hints in-game. But typically, the location of the bobblehead or any other collectible is in a important location in regard to the area you are in.

For example, the bobblehead may be in the same room as the area boss or quest objective.

You can also consult the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_bobblehead#Fallout_4) if you can't find a specific bobblehead.

Comment: thanks. well, I will have to "pixel peep" every location.